# Как считать данные с банковской nfc карты?

Tags: arduino, nfc

Проблема такая: есть кампусная карта, она же пропуск. Проблема в том, что её могут считать только считыватели на турникете. Купил модуль rfid rc 522. Хочется считать с неё данные и записать их в брелок, а лучше если в эмулятор карт на телефоне с nfc. Хз какие какие данные считываются, по этому нужно хотя бы uid.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код, который у вас уже есть.

Comment: RFID может использовать разные частоты, я не уверен, что NFC на телефоне сможет сэмулировать пропускную карту.

Comment: Код брал из примеров библиотеки для ардуино rfid rc 522

Comment: Если не получится сэмулировать с телефона, то хотя бы перенести данные на другую карту-брелок